# ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\...\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

Tags: visual-studio-code, dart, flutter

I updated Flutter to the `0.11.9` version. If I create a new project using Flutter extension for Visual Studio Code and then I run ‘Start Without Debugging’, I receive this error message:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\marco\Downloads\Prova\ciao\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout of 120000 reached waiting for exclusive access to file: C:\Users\marco\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.10.2-all\9fahxiiecdb76a5g3aw9oi8rv\gradle-4.10.2-all.zip

    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:61)

    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)

    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)

    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
  Command: C:\Users\marco\Downloads\Prova\ciao\android\gradlew.bat -v
Exited (sigterm)
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks!

**EDIT**

It is strange, because, *after* solving the problem about Android licenses, if I re-run `flutter doctor`, I receive this message:

```
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.1)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\marco\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.1
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)
    X Android license status unknown.
```

Comment: Have you tried running `flutter doctor`?

Comment: Yes. I resolved a problem with the license, and now is all OK with `flutter doctor`. But the error is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows in `gradlew.bat` do the following changes:

- First Change

  - **Find**: `set CLASSPATH=%APP_HOME%\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.jar`
  - **Replace**: `set CLASSPATH=<path_to_downloaded_gardle>\gradle-4.6\lib\gradle-launcher-4.6.jar`
- Second Change

  - **Find**: `"%JAVA_EXE%" %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS% %JAVA_OPTS% %GRADLE_OPTS% "-Dorg.gradle.appname=%APP_BASE_NAME%" -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain %CMD_LINE_ARGS%`
  - **Replace**: `"%JAVA_EXE%" %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS% %JAVA_OPTS% %GRADLE_OPTS% "-Dorg.gradle.appname=%APP_BASE_NAME%" -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain %CMD_LINE_ARGS%`

Comment: Thank you! With Flutter 1.0 I have not this problem, but your answer could be useful in the future.